# Subtables with equal width?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create two subtables with equal width (and horizontally aligned),
but the second table is getting rendered (pdflatex) smaller than the first one even with equal width specified. Changing the width of the second table shifted it to the right. Can someone help?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{\textbf{blabla.} bla.}\label{tblfoo}
  \centering

\begin{subtable}[t]{\textwidth}
  \centering
\caption{RefSeq-derived synthetic metagenome}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrr@{}}

  & Kraken & Kaiju & Centrifuge & MetaPhlAn 2 & MGX \\

\midrule

TP & 12,059,412 & 9,329,288 & 12,611,380 & 414,943 & 12,566,362 \\
FP & 18,748 & 185,899 & 53,092 & 7,171 & 20,698 \\
FN & 1,281,840 & 3,844,813 & 695,528 & 12,937,886 & 772,940 \\

\midrule

Sensitivity & 0.9039 & 0.7082 & \textbf{0.9477} & 0.0311 & 0.9421 \\
Precision & \textbf{0.9984} & 0.9805 & 0.9958 & 0.9830 & \textbf{0.9984} \\
Accuracy & 0.9027 & 0.6983 & \textbf{0.9440} & 0.0311 & 0.9406 \\
F1 score & 0.9488 & 0.8224 & \textbf{0.9712} & 0.0602 & 0.9694 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\vspace*{5mm}
\centering

\begin{subtable}[t]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{GenBank-derived synthetic metagenome}

\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrr@{}}

  & Kraken & Kaiju & Centrifuge & MetaPhlAn 2 & MGX \\

\midrule

TP & 1,851,436 & 2,592,655 & 2,175,122 & 92,383 & 3,976,270 \\
FP & 398,899 & 1,230,445 & 864,989 & 10,378 & 734,389 \\
FN & 9,629,665 & 8,56,900 & 8,839,889 & 11,777,239 & 7,169,341 \\

\midrule

Sensitivity & 0.1613 & 0.2435 & 0.1975 & 0.0078 & \textbf{0.3568} \\
Precision & 0.8227 & 0.6782 & 0.7155 & \textbf{0.8990} & 0.8441 \\
Accuracy & 0.1558 & 0.2182 & 0.1831 & 0.0078 & \textbf{0.3347} \\
F1 score & 0.2697 & 0.3583 & 0.3095 & 0.0154 & \textbf{0.5015} \\

\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the users of TeX.SE. Generally to align numbers well within a table where there are semicolons it is good to use [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

Comment: You have not ser any width for the tables (tabulars) environments, only for a containing box. For tables of fixed width, you have the `tabularx` and `tabulary` packages or the `tabular*` environment. You can also use only fixed width columns as `p{2cm}` in  pain tabular if reach the witdh `\textwidth` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use `tabular*` instead of `tabular` environments. In particular, you may want to set both target widths to `\textwidth`, as is done in the following example.

A separate suggestion: I would use "unextended" bold (as opposed to the TeX default "extended bold") for tabular numbers, so that non-bold and bold tabular numerals have the same widths.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\captionsetup[subtable]{size=normalsize, skip=0.5\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\ubold}[1]{\fontseries{b}\selectfont #1} % non-extended bold

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX determine intercolumn whitespace

\caption{\textbf{blabla.} bla.}\label{tblfoo}


\begin{subtable}[t]{\textwidth}
\caption{RefSeq-derived synthetic metagenome}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrrrr}
  & Kraken & Kaiju & Centrifuge & MetaPhlAn 2 & MGX \\
\midrule
TP & 12,059,412 & 9,329,288 & 12,611,380 & 414,943 & 12,566,362 \\
FP & 18,748 & 185,899 & 53,092 & 7,171 & 20,698 \\
FN & 1,281,840 & 3,844,813 & 695,528 & 12,937,886 & 772,940 \\
\midrule
Sensitivity & 0.9039 & 0.7082 & \ubold{0.9477} & 0.0311 & 0.9421 \\
Precision & \ubold{0.9984} & 0.9805 & 0.9958 & 0.9830 & \ubold{0.9984} \\
Accuracy & 0.9027 & 0.6983 & \ubold{0.9440} & 0.0311 & 0.9406 \\
F1 score & 0.9488 & 0.8224 & \ubold{0.9712} & 0.0602 & 0.9694 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\vspace*{5mm}

\begin{subtable}[t]{\textwidth}
\caption{GenBank-derived synthetic metagenome}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lrrrrr}
  & Kraken & Kaiju & Centrifuge & MetaPhlAn 2 & MGX \\
\midrule
TP & 1,851,436 & 2,592,655 & 2,175,122 & 92,383 & 3,976,270 \\
FP & 398,899 & 1,230,445 & 864,989 & 10,378 & 734,389 \\
FN & 9,629,665 & 8,56,900 & 8,839,889 & 11,777,239 & 7,169,341 \\
\midrule
Sensitivity & 0.1613 & 0.2435 & 0.1975 & 0.0078 & \ubold{0.3568} \\
Precision & 0.8227 & 0.6782 & 0.7155 & \ubold{0.8990} & 0.8441 \\
Accuracy & 0.1558 & 0.2182 & 0.1831 & 0.0078 & \ubold{0.3347} \\
F1 score & 0.2697 & 0.3583 & 0.3095 & 0.0154 & \ubold{0.5015} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Less elegant and less automated than [Mico's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493816/134144) but you can use `\widthof` to measure the width of the widest entry in the column of the first table and use this width for the corresponding column in the second table (column 2 and 6 in your example):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{\textbf{blabla.} bla.}\label{tblfoo}
  \centering

\begin{subtable}[t]{\textwidth}
  \centering
\caption{RefSeq-derived synthetic metagenome}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrrrr@{}}

  & Kraken & Kaiju & Centrifuge & MetaPhlAn 2 & MGX \\

\midrule

TP & 12,059,412 & 9,329,288 & 12,611,380 & 414,943 & 12,566,362 \\
FP & 18,748 & 185,899 & 53,092 & 7,171 & 20,698 \\
FN & 1,281,840 & 3,844,813 & 695,528 & 12,937,886 & 772,940 \\

\midrule

Sensitivity & 0.9039 & 0.7082 & \textbf{0.9477} & 0.0311 & 0.9421 \\
Precision & \textbf{0.9984} & 0.9805 & 0.9958 & 0.9830 & \textbf{0.9984} \\
Accuracy & 0.9027 & 0.6983 & \textbf{0.9440} & 0.0311 & 0.9406 \\
F1 score & 0.9488 & 0.8224 & \textbf{0.9712} & 0.0602 & 0.9694 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\vspace*{5mm}
\centering

\begin{subtable}[t]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \caption{GenBank-derived synthetic metagenome}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l>{\RaggedLeft}p{\widthof{12,059,412}}rrr>{\RaggedLeft}p{\widthof{12,566,362}}@{}}

  & Kraken & Kaiju & Centrifuge & MetaPhlAn 2 & MGX \\

\midrule

TP & 1,851,436 & 2,592,655 & 2,175,122 & 92,383 & 3,976,270 \\
FP & 398,899 & 1,230,445 & 864,989 & 10,378 & 734,389 \\
FN & 9,629,665 & 8,56,900 & 8,839,889 & 11,777,239 & 7,169,341 \\

\midrule

Sensitivity & 0.1613 & 0.2435 & 0.1975 & 0.0078 & \textbf{0.3568} \\
Precision & 0.8227 & 0.6782 & 0.7155 & \textbf{0.8990} & 0.8441 \\
Accuracy & 0.1558 & 0.2182 & 0.1831 & 0.0078 & \textbf{0.3347} \\
F1 score & 0.2697 & 0.3583 & 0.3095 & 0.0154 & \textbf{0.5015} \\

\bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{subtable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or, simply insert a `\phantom{0}` directive immediately before `1,851,436`?

Comment: Perfect, I converted to tabular* and added \phantom{0} - that solved it. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: @Mico: Great idea that did not come to my mind.